# Pandas: Selecting rows and columns based on a subset of columns that contain a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with column names as follows:

`col_id_1, col_id_2, ..., col_id_m, property_1, property_2 ..., property_n`

As an example, how would I search across all `col_id`s for, say, the value `5` (note that `5` won't appear in multiple `col_id`s in the same row), and then choose all rows that contain this value? On top of that, once I've found all rows that have a `col_id` containing the value `5`, I'll combine all the `col_id`s with value `5` into a single `id` column, and also only choose, say, `property_8` and `property_25000` as additional columns.

In this case, I would have a table with the following columns:

`id, property_8, property_25000`

where the `id` column only contains rows with value `5`. Is such a thing possible in pandas?

Comment: Could you add to your question an input dataframe example, as well as an example of the desired result dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, first `filter` you columns by contain the `col_id`, then we using any check if `any` columns have the number 5

```
df.loc[df.filter(like='col_id').eq(5).any(1),['property_8','property_25000']].assign(id=5)
```

Comment: _"... (note that 5 won't appear in multiple col_ids in the same row)... "_ - `any` instead of `all`, then it's perfect.

Comment: Somebody think that this answer is [low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23047226), maybe because of no explanation.

Comment: @SpghttCd undeleted :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @WeNYoBen, unfortunately I set my question up incorrectly and left out one more vital piece of information. I think I'll have to start a new topic.

Comment: @indigoblue if that is the case , would you like accept one of then answer ?

Comment: I've posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225950/selecting-rows-and-columns-based-on-a-subset-of-rows-and-columns-that-contain-a

Answer (score 0):

You can refine this answer with creative list comprehension (for col names). One simple approach may be to subset using OR `|` ... alternatively AND `&`

`df_new = df[(df['col_id_1'] == 5) | (df['col_id_2'] == 5) | (df['col_id_3'] == 5)]`

`df_new` will represent a dataframe reflecting your parameters, you can then just subset the columns accordingly

`df_new = df_new[['id', 'propert_8', 'property_25000']]`

Comment: Thanks for the attempted answer. It seems that this would require a little bit too much manual typing if we have, say, 1e6 `col_id`s.